# C++: Expression must have a constant value when declaring array inside function

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, constants

I have looked at all the other posts with a similar topic, and none help, so please don't flag as a duplicate.

I am defining in `main()` a `const int SIZE = 20;`. Then, I pass this as an argument to my function, Mode:

```
int* Mode(int* numbers, int & mode, const int SIZE)
 {
     int occurences[SIZE];

     // Calcualte mode
 }
```

However, I get the error, `expression must have a constant value`.

My function call (in main) looks like this:

```
int* occurencesPtr = Mode(numbersPtr, mode, SIZE);
```

With `SIZE` being defined at the beginning to the literal `20`.

I understand that the error is because the function's version of `SIZE` only acquires its value when the function is called (?), but I don't know how I could work around this.

I have even tried passing to the function a `const int * const SIZEPtr = &SIZE`, but that didn't work either. Help?

**EDIT: I am *not* trying to use a variable size!! Notice that I have made `SIZE` a `const` everywhere! I just want to use that same SIZE constant to declare my array.**

EDIT: Dynamic arrays are not what I need. I just want a normal, named, array, defined with a **constant** size value passed to the function.

Comment: 100% duplicate. use the search with your exact title. Look for "dynamic" in the answers.

Comment: Variable Length Arrays are not Standard C++. While they are supported by some compilers as an extension there is no guarantee it will be available when switching to a different toolchain.

Comment: int *occurences = new int[SIZE]; .... ;  delete(occurences);

Comment: What you want in the way you want it is not possible in Standard C++.

Comment: (the reason being that new int[SIZE]; allocates the array in the heap, while int occurences[SIZE]; allocates it into the stack (i.e. in the middle of the local variables of the function))

Comment: Thank you, @user1952009, that worked.

Comment: The size *is* variable because it is passed as a function parameter, and "constant" != "const". Read the error as saying "must have a fixed value". It must be known at the time of definition, not at run time, otherwise it's a dynamic array.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a misconception here with what `const` means, probably because it's a little confusing that this works:

```
const int SIZE = 20;
int array[SIZE];
```

but this doesn't:

```
void foo(const int SIZE) {
    int array[SIZE];
    // ...
}

const int SIZE = 20;
foo(SIZE);
```

The issue is that the array size in an array declaration must be a core constant expression. Simplified, that means an expression that's evaluatable at compile time to be a constant. That is true in the first case (you can see that `SIZE` is the integral constant `20`) but that is *not* true in the second case. There, the `SIZE` function parameter is just `const` - in the sense that it is nonmodifiable - and not a core constant expression. You can see the difference in that I can call `foo()` with something that is clearly unknowable until runtime:

```
int x;
if (std::cin >> x) {
    foo(x);
}
```

In order to pass an argument into `foo`, and have that argument be used as an array bound, it is not enough to have it be `const` - the actual integral value must be encoded into the type (unless you call `foo()` as `constexpr` which I'm assuming is not the case here). In which case, you'd have to do something like:

```
template <int SIZE>
void foo() { ... }

const int SIZE = 20;
foo<SIZE>();
```

or:

```
template <int SIZE>
void foo(std::integral_constant<int, SIZE > ) { ... }

const int SIZE = 20;
foo(std::integral_constant<int, SIZE>{} );
```

or simply have `SIZE` be a global constant or otherwise accessible to `foo()` in a way that doesn't have to do with its arguments.

---

Or, there's always the simple option: use `std::vector`:

```
void foo(const int SIZE) {
    std::vector<int> v(SIZE);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that cleared a lot of things up. I'm very new to C++, and I actually have no idea what a template is or what it does, but it works :)

Answer (score 5):

> I understand that the error is because the function's version of SIZE only acquires its value when the function is called (?), but I don't know how I could work around this.

**Option 1**

Instead of defining `SIZE` in `main`, add a `constexpr` function. Use the `constexpr` function instead of passing the size.

```
constexpr int getSize()
{
   return 20;
}

int* Mode(int* numbers, int & mode)
{
   int occurences[getSize()];

   // ...

}
```

**Option 2**

Use `std::vector` instead of array.

```
int* Mode(int* numbers, int & mode, int size)
{
   std::vector<int> occurences[size];

   // ...

}
```

**Option 3**

Use a function template.

```
template <size_t SIZE>
int* Mode(int* numbers, int & mode, int size)
{
   int occurences[SIZE];

   // ...

}
```

**Option 4**

Use a function template and `std::array`.

```
template <size_t SIZE>
int* Mode(int* numbers, int & mode, int size)
{
   std::array<int, SIZE> occurences;

   // ...

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You're confusing things. A `constant expression` has nothing to do with `const` (at least not that much) ;).

let's think we are the compiler and face this function:

```
void foo(const int SIZE) { }
```

The `const`merely says "we are not able to change the function-local variable `SIZE` inside the function body. 
We need to compile it without assuming that `SIZE` is compile time constant. Why?

Because there is noone stoping us from doing something like:

```
int i{};
std::cin >> i;
foo(i);
```

You can pass any (matching/convertible) value to a by value `const` function argument.

What should happen when the compiler assumed the value passed to `foo` was a compile time constant expression?

If you want to pass compile time constants, use templates and while you're at it use `std::array` instead of `T[N]`:

```
template<std::size_t N>
void foo()
{
    std::array<int, N> occurences;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`const` isn't doing what you think it's doing in your `Mode` function.

When `const` is used in function definition, `const` is simply telling the compiler that the function will not change the argument declared `const` inside of the scope of it's function. *But that does not make the argument a constant, it is actually called a constant expression.* Some compilers enforce this, others do not, and so will allow you to change `const` expressions (arguments passed with `const` keyword).

In order to use a globally accessible constant value which you can use, like `SIZE`, you'll need to declare a global constant before the function is called; which could be declared outside of `main()`, or at least outside the scope of all other functions but `main()`, if you must declare all inside main. Pass the global constant to the `Mode` function just as you would any other variable.

Oh, and, `main()` needs a return type.

I've edited the code to meet your specific constraints.

Here is a variation on your original code:

```
int main(){
    //Declare constants first.
    const int SIZE = 20; /*Could declare here instead.*/

    //Declare variables next.
    int *intPtr = 0; // to hold the pointer passed from Mode.
    int *numbersPointer = 0;
    int mode = 0;

    //Define Mode (using OP's code.)
    int* Mode(int* numbers, int & mode, const int size){
        int occurences[size];
         // Calculate mode
    }

    /*Now use constants, variables, and functions.*/

    intPtr = Mode(numbersPointer, mode, SIZE); //Call mode.

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this program is for an assignment, and my teacher's policy is no global constants or variables, so I won't be able to use this. Useful for future reference, though :)

Comment: No problem, always glad to help a fellow student! I've modified the code to meet your needs better. PM me if you need help.

Comment: It is strange your teacher won't allow global constants - those are safe to use. I've not known a teacher yet to discourage them, even in beginning classes. Certainly global variables are unsafe though, and should rarely be used, if ever. I'd ask for some clarification from your teacher on global constants.

Comment: woah woah woah... How did you declare a function inside of Main()?

Comment: It's possible (but not recommended) to declare a function inside of main in C++. It's better to declare functions outside of main, so other functions can access each other, but so long as all functions share the same scope, it's okay.